# Difference Between SQL Expressions and Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

From what I understand, conditions are statements that evaluate to true, false, or unknown. I don't understand how this differs from a SQL expression, however.

What is the difference between the two and could examples be provided to illustrate this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions are allowed to produce results of any type supported by your RDBMS. For example, `Salary+Bonus` below is an example of an expression:

```
SELECT
    Salary
,   Bonus
,   Salary+Bonus AS TotalCompensation
FROM EmployeeCompensation
WHERE EmployeeId=1223
```

Conditions are expressions that evaluate to `true`, `false`, or `NULL` (unknown). These are the only expressions allowed in `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses. `EmployeeId=1223` above is an example of a condition.

Answer (score 4):

As you said: conditions (predicates) return a boolean values (three-valued in case of SQL).

Things that return other types, are still expressions:

- `1+1`
- `SUBSTRING(...)`

A condition (predicate) is just a expression with the return type `boolean`.

- `1 > 0`
- `1 < 0`
- `1 = null`